В обработке по загрузке данных из Excel возникает ошибка (скрин). Помогите решить
[
Сам код:
 &НаКлиенте
    Процедура ПутьКФайлуНачалоВыбора(Элемент, ДанныеВыбора, ВыборДобавлением, СтандартнаяОбработка)
        Проводник=Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие);
        Проводник.Заголовок="Выберите Файл";
        Оповещение = Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ПослеВыбораФайла", ЭтотОбъект);
        Проводник.Показать(Оповещение); 
    КонецПроцедуры 

                     

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПослеВыбораФайла(ВыбранныеФайлы, ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт
    
    Если ВыбранныеФайлы = Неопределено Тогда
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;
    
    Объект.ПутьКФайлу = ВыбранныеФайлы[0];
    

КонецПроцедуры


&НаКлиенте
Процедура ЗагрузитьДанныеИзExcel(Команда) 
    
    ПутьКФайлу= ВыбратьФайл();             
    
    Если ПутьКФайлу=Неопределено Тогда 
        Предупреждение("Файл не выбран");
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;
    
    
    Книга = Excel.Workbooks.Open(ПутьКФайлу);
    Лист = Книга.Worksheets(1);

    
    НомерСтроки = ВвестиНомерСтроки();

    Если НомерСтроки = Неопределено Тогда
        Предупреждение("Номер строки не введен!");
        Возврат;
    КонецЕсли;

    
    ДанныеСтроки = Лист.Rows(НомерСтроки).Value;

    
    Книга.Close();
    Excel.Quit();

    ОбработатьДанные(ДанныеСтроки);

    Сообщить("Данные успешно загружены!");
КонецПроцедуры                            
&НаКлиенте
Функция ВыбратьНомерСтроки() Экспорт

    ФормаВвода = ПолучитьФорму("ОбщаяФорма.ИмяТвоейФормы");
    Поле = ФормаВвода.Элементы.Добавить("НомерСтроки", Тип("Число"));
    ФормаВвода.ОткрытьМодально();
    Возврат Поле.Значение;  

КонецФункции


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

и ошибку текстом надо

Стоп, как это ты пытаешься создать форму? В 1С нет такого конструктора..
Вместо
ФормаВвода = Новый Форма;
Тебе нужно получать уже существующую форму и менять её, затем показывать
Вот так:
Форма = ЭтотОбъект.ПолучитьФорму("Форма");   
Форма.ЭлементыФормы.Добавить(Тип("ПолеВвода"),"Поле1",Истина, ЭлементыФормы.КоманднаяПанель):
Форма.ОткрытьМодально();

И очень советую почитать синтаксис команды - ЭлементыФормы.Добавить.
